# How does Aerospike handle the external hardware efficiently in comparison to mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aerospike

I was working on one Data migration project in which we were migrating the data from MongoDb to Aerospike. While I was going through the documentation I found Aerospike uses 'In Memory' concept for handling the fragmentation of memory.
But, I was wondering for example, if we have a 16GB Ram of Machine with 10Tb of storage, what difference does Aerospike create at Software level or more precisely how does Aerospike handles such scenarios, where data is huge and yet we are getting much better performance results at SOFTWARE  level.
Even if question is not clear yet....
We have  got machine with above mentioned configuration for both MongoDb and Aerospike. What makes Aerospike faster.

Answer (score 2):

Its because of the underlying design. Aerospike is designed to provide ultra fast performance at individual record read-write level. I created a 24 min video on youtube, 3 years ago - its probably the quickest way to answer your question. Or it will be a very long post. So if you are interested, watch it. It explains the basic architecture of Aerospike and how it distributes data which explains why its superfast. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PA7PGWphW8M&t=450s You can also get free access to a longer course on Aerospike Academy if you register on the website.